# Problem with switches on a toy circuit board

Tags: pcb, switches

I am trying to find out what's wrong with a toy train. There are two 4 pin switches on the board - one to start the train and another for a sound effect. The problem is that when I press one of the switches nothing happens. When I press the sound switch and keep it pressed, then press the motor switch, I hear the sound and vice versa - when I press the motor switch and hold it, then press the sound switch, the motor starts. My question is, how do I diagnose what's wrong - is it one of the solder joints, one of the switches, or something else? [image: Picture of the circuit board]

Answer (score 1):

The fact that both switches are misbehaving in the same way suggests that something that is in common has failed, rather than one of the switches or connections to it.

Unfortunately, it's not obvious what that would be. (The worst case is that it is actually the controller IC under the blob.)

I think you will have to figure out what the circuit is intended to be by following all the traces (e.g. the switches probably have one side in common but does it lead to Vcc or GND?) and making a schematic, then probing around with a voltmeter (or an oscilloscope if you have one) to see where the real signals disagree with what *should* be there given the schematic.

Answer (score 0):

Input Logic for switches m,n seems incorrect with conditional inputs  yet expected to be independent.

If the switch is 4 pin, could it be 1P2T or 2P1T?  then it may be rotated or installed incorrectly.

I would expect Motor function to be toggle latched and speaker to be momentary

Something got lost in translation at the   chinese  factory?